# Why do thumbs change in this asynctask load adapter?

Tags: gridview, android-asynctask, thumbnails

I've made an image viewer that shows thumbnails. The thumbnails are bitmaps populated inside a gridview, with a custom BaseAdapter. Works fine, but the app freezes just a bit to populate the gridview (the good point is that all thumbs are shown at once, and without strange behaviours).

Then, to avoid the small freeze, I decided to load bitmaps with an asynctask. The problem I have is that when I scroll, I see the thumbnails *changing* from one image to another, instead of staying the same (or black). By scrolling fast, I can see strange behaviours... When everything is loaded, the thumbs don't change anymore, unless I scroll very fast. It is like if each element in the gridview has something cached...

Any clues what is happening, and how I can avoid this?

This is the relevant part of my code, inside the custom BaseAdapter:

```
class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        ...
        class MakeBitmap extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
        WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
        public MakeBitmap(ImageView imageView) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... param) {
            String fi = (String) files.toArray()[param[0]];
            if (!fi.isEmpty()) {
                String fith = FName.th(fi, true);
                if ((new File(fith)).isFile())
                    myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fith);
                else {
                    myBitmap = CreateThumbnail(fith);
                }
            }
            return myBitmap;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (imageViewReference != null) {
                ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(thumbsize, thumbsize));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        (new MakeBitmap(imageView)).execute(pos);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```